# Uniqueness of finite continued fractions expansions

Tags: arithmetic, continued-fractions

Under which condition on $a_0, \dots , a_n$ the continued fraction expansion of a positive rational number $$r= a_0- \frac{1}{ \ddots -\frac{1}{a_n}}$$ is unique?

Comment: $a_i\geq 2.\phantom{}$

Comment: So, any positive rational number has a unique finite continued fraction expansion with the $a_i \geq 2$?

Comment: Any rational number $\geq 1$. That happens since $x=1$ is the only fixed point of the map $x\to 2-\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: But I need something also in the case $0 \leq x \leq 1$ !!!

Comment: If you are able to represent any $x\in\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 1}$ as a negative continued fraction and you have a rational number $y\in(0,1)$, you may represent $\frac{1}{y}$, too.

Comment: Yes, i already solved my problem with this trick :)